# Find all possible paths in a graph with a time constraint

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

My data looks like the following :

```
      source  target
time                
0.5    96253   94861
1.0    96652   95091
1.5    94861   95091
2.5    95091   95409
3.5    95409   97221
4.5    97221   96781
5.5    96781   97707
6.5    97707   98191
7.5    98191   99096
8.5    99096  100016
8.5    99096  100013
9.5   100013   98663
9.5   100016   98658
10.5   98658   99573
10.5   98663   99589
11.5   99589  100506
11.5   99573  100490
```

- Each integers inside `source` and `target` columns reference a spots.
- Each row is a link between two spots.
- The `time` index refers to the time point in which the link can be found.

A smart algorithm would be to found all the possible trajectories contained inside the dataset.

For example in the previous example, 4 trajectories exist :

```
[96253, 94861, 95091, 95409, 97221, 97221, 96781, 97707, 98191, 99096, 100016, 98658, 99573, 100490]
[96652, 95091, 95409, 97221, 97221, 96781, 97707, 98191, 99096, 100016, 98658, 99573, 100490]
[96253, 94861, 95091, 95409, 97221, 97221, 96781, 97707, 98191, 99096, 100013, 98663, 99589, 100506]
[96652, 95091, 95409, 97221, 97221, 96781, 97707, 98191, 99096, 100013, 98663, 99589, 100506]
```

---

This problem can be resumed as a graph theory problem. See the below graph which corresponds to the data showed at the beginning.

[image]

The idea would be to find all possible paths in this graph **with** a constraint respecting time logic : a trajectory is an ordered list of spots (nodes) which can only go from `t` to `t+1` (can't go in past).

---

The algorithm will be implemented in Python. So any Python tricks are allowed :-)

Comment: It isn't exactly clear to me how the trajectory is built up, i.e. why 95091 connects to 94861, 95409 and 96652, for example. Also, have you had a go at writing some of the algorithm and coding it? If so please post your code. Also, I'd recommend having a look at this library if you haven't already: https://www.udacity.com/wiki/creating-network-graphs-with-python

Comment: The source dataset is coming from a software (TrackMate plugin for Fiji) which inside a unique track, mix different split and merge events. This is why a single spot can have 2 spots in the future. It comes from the fact that this single spot is in fact 2 spots. Is that clear enough ?

Answer (score 1):

Applying graph theory algorithm seems to be the smart way to resolve this. I used `networkx` python library.

```py
print(spot_ids)
```

output :

```
      source  target
time                
0.5    96253   94861
1.0    96652   95091
1.5    94861   95091
2.5    95091   95409
3.5    95409   97221
4.5    97221   96781
5.5    96781   97707
6.5    97707   98191
7.5    98191   99096
8.5    99096  100016
8.5    99096  100013
9.5   100013   98663
9.5   100016   98658
10.5   98658   99573
10.5   98663   99589
11.5   99589  100506
11.5   99573  100490
```

The algorithm :

```py
import itertools
import networkx as nx

# Build graph
graph = nx.Graph()
for t, spot in spot_ids.iterrows():
    graph.add_edge(int(spot['source']), int(spot['target']), attr_dict=dict(t=t))

# Find graph extremities by checking if number of neighbors is equal to 1
tracks_extremities = [node for node in graph.nodes() if len(graph.neighbors(node)) == 1]
tracks_extremities

paths = []
# Find all possible paths between extremities
for source, target in itertools.combinations(tracks_extremities, 2):

    # Find all path between two nodes
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(graph, source=source, target=target):

        # Now we need to check wether this path respect the time logic contraint
        # edges can only go in one direction of the time

        # Build times vector according to path
        t = []
        for i, node_srce in enumerate(path[:-1]):
            node_trgt = path[i+1]
            t.append(graph.edge[node_srce][node_trgt]['t'])

        # Will be equal to 1 if going to one time direction
        if len(np.unique(np.sign(np.diff(t)))) == 1:
            paths.append(path)

for path in paths:
    print(path)
```

output :

```
[100490, 99573, 98658, 100016, 99096, 98191, 97707, 96781, 97221, 95409, 95091, 96652]
[100490, 99573, 98658, 100016, 99096, 98191, 97707, 96781, 97221, 95409, 95091, 94861, 96253]
[96652, 95091, 95409, 97221, 96781, 97707, 98191, 99096, 100013, 98663, 99589, 100506]
[100506, 99589, 98663, 100013, 99096, 98191, 97707, 96781, 97221, 95409, 95091, 94861, 96253]
```

Comment: Hmm looks like an ok solution, but the number of paths can quickly grow very very large, thus the `for path in ...` loop might find a lot of results. I have a feeling that by doing some clever path finding yourself, you might be able to do a lot better, time-complexity wise.

Comment: That is correct for some dataset but for my use case, in reality my dataset will contain only few multiples paths. This is why I didn't take time to hard optimize it.

Comment: If you found a more optimized algorithm, please feel free to post your answer.